# Microsoft Office Excel 2010 - IF Statement, Calculating Date

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2010

I've got stuck with IF statement in Excel 2010. Exercise is going like this: "Student is INACTIVE if he didn't login to website more then a year, else he's active."

Since I've been not using Excel for years, and now I'm forced to because of university, can you guys help me about this, I'd be really thankfull.

No matter what I do, everyone is ACTIVE or INACTIVE, depends on my IF statement, I was going like: Mark one field > 365, value if true="Active", value if false="Inactive", but seems not to work out.

```
=IF(D5-TODAY()>365,"Active","Inactive");
```

doesn't seem to work out.

Here is a screenshot: https://i.stack.imgur.com/H8kUY.png

Comment: `=IF(TODAY()-D5<365,"Active","Inactive")`

Comment: Your dates seem in a non North American traditional format. Are you sure that Excel is parsing these cells as dates?

Comment: In same exercise, we had to format date, so instead of number it writes name of month, in this case November. I'll check that out now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`=IF(TODAY()-D5<365,"Active","Inactive")`

I would suggest putting the `TODAY()` function in on cell, and then use that ONE cell in multiple formulas. Like so:

`=IF($A$1-D5<365,"Active","Inactive")` - considering formula in `$A$1` is `=TODAY()`

### Alternative

Instead of days count, you can use `EDATE` for calculating exact date 12 months ago. Then use that as your criteria.

[image]

Comment: =IF(TODAY()-D5<365,"Active","Inactive")

is giving me error, I need to fix my formula.

Comment: What error are you getting? If you apply general formatting to the D5 cell, does it change to whole number, or does it stay the same, showing the text?

Comment: Thanks for helping by the way,

so basically I formated D5 cell, changed Date to 11.11.2016, formula is same and getting this error:

Comment: Check your separators. This type of error you get, when you use comma `,` instead of semicolon `;` or vice versa. Or using dot `.` instead of comma `,` etc.

Comment: Thanks, formula is working but It's kinda wrong. For example, first user last time logged in to website in November this year, and he's active, so that's fine, but next user last logged in 2010 which is way more then 365 days and it says he's also active, so... what's wrong now... and thanks once again...

Comment: Try putting a formula `=TODAY()-D5` next to each date in the list. You will get a count of days between today and the date in the list. If you get more days than expected, there is a problem with the input data in the list.  And, you're welcome, for help, and on SO. :)

Comment: It's problem with the input data, but I've figured out how this formula works. Many thanks for this help, God bless ya.